# Custom assemblies not being referenced in Views

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

If a custom c# assembly is used in a *View*, the compiler fails to find the reference to the namespace.
It works if the assembly is referenced and called within a query but not from a view.

For instance, consider this U-SQL script for creating a view: 
The assemblies being used are registered in *mylocaldb* before running this query, and are available to be accessed in any script.

```
USE DATABASE mylocaldb;

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

USING Newtonsoft.Json;
USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS SearchAccountData;
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
EXTRACT
    UserId string,
    UserName string        
FROM "Data/mydata.json"
USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();
```

After the execution of the script, the view gets created and stored an under *Views* in the *mylocaldb* database.

Upon using the view in another query:

```
USE DATABASE mylocaldb;
USE SCHEMA dbo;

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

USING Newtonsoft.Json;
USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

@foo= SELECT * FROM MyView;

OUTPUT @foo
TO  "/output/foo.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

(the `USE SCHEMA dbo` isn't necessary as the database defaults to that in case no other schema is being used):

the compiler throws an error:

```
E_CSC_USER_INVALIDCSHARP: C# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Samples' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Analytics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Now this might be conflicting with the library that comes with U-SQL: `Microsoft.Analytics`, but I have tried using another assembly with a different namespace, and I still have the same issue.

I am testing locally using the (Local) account in VisualStudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to use a `PROCEDURE`. 
In *Views* UDFs (User Defined Functions) or UDOs can't be used.

Views cannot:

- Contain user-defined objects (such as UDFs or UDOs).
- Will be inlined upon call.

This information can be found here on slide 27 at [U-SQL - Azure Data Lake Analytics for Developers](http://www.slideshare.net/MichaelRys/usql-azure-data-lake-analytics-for-developers)

It would be helpful if this was mentioned in U-SQL Language Reference docs for [Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621328.aspx).

Unlike Views, procedures and table-valued functions have support for UDFs and can include Reference to assemblies:.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExtractTransactions(@data_stream string = @"Data/{*}")
AS BEGIN

    REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
    REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

    USING Newtonsoft.Json;
    USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

    @transactions =
        EXTRACT
            UserId string,
            UserName string        
        FROM @data_stream 
        USING new JsonExtractor();

    INSERT INTO ExtractedTransactions
    SELECT * FROM @transactions;
END;
```

And then simply call the procedure from another query:

`ExtractTransactions(DEFAULT)` (where `DEFAULT` is the default parameter).

Comment: Correct and I will file a ticket to update the documentation. Great to see you were able to find the information so quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mike & sponturious. U-SQL Language Reference has been updated at CREATE VIEW (U-SQL) under the Query_Expression section at the official U-SQL Language Reference site

(Note: Would provide a link but the Gods keep deleting my responses when I do.  Just do a search for "CREATE VIEW (U-SQL)".)